# Multiindex reindexing using datetime component as level

Tags: pandas

I can't for the life of me figure this out. I'm trying to reindex a dataframe based on two columns of my dataframe:

```
Index        Donation      AbsSiz         Affil                                           DonID            Datetime_Obj
19               2000    25598000           Con            ffed93a8-2c3d-770c-1e67-e76b2d7ec738 2018-07-31 17:03:35.791
20                360     4607640           Lib            62d87d76-478d-4c09-9ecb-03d32dfc7941 2018-07-31 17:03:35.791
21                 60      767940           Con            fc53a961-036c-4043-01aa-57ccfa839ee5 2018-07-31 17:03:35.791
22                 70      895930           Lib            d1c81281-8f0b-e991-d8ed-6031ac66af92 2018-07-31 17:03:35.791
23                 27      345573           Con            135fa1b5-2304-c761-0df7-147132c35cd8 2018-07-31 17:03:35.791
24               8206   105028594           Con            7aef85bd-bc67-9905-8614-aac65e2ae21e 2018-07-31 17:03:35.791
25                 32      409600           Lib            03f7c33a-920e-67db-78bd-640e8009c8a2 2018-07-31 17:03:35.791
26              28000   358400000           Con            0a2c264c-bc81-69f7-d8fe-05b521d79d9a 2018-07-31 17:03:35.791
27                230     2944000           Con            4e868220-7687-8acc-c3bd-f09624c4d15b 2018-07-31 17:03:35.791
28                  3       38400           Con            5e57de8d-3f37-d943-af95-0834dcaf8efd 2018-07-31 17:03:35.791
```

My aim is to reindex this so that all of the rows under the same dt.minute for datetime_obj are grouped together, with the other level indexing to group based of Affil are together.

I know this is probably simple but I've been hiting head against a brick wall for hours.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you mean by "re-index", but taken at face value I'll set the DataFrame index to the minute and Affil

```
df['datetime_obj_min'] = df['datetime_ob'].dt.minute
df.set_index(['datetime_obj_min', 'Affil'], inplace=True, drop=True)
```

You mentioned wanting to group by, but no aggregation that you wanted to perform.  Here's an example of summing donation by minute and Affil:

```
df['datetime_obj_min'] = df['datetime_ob'].dt.minute
df.groupby(['datetime_obj_min', 'Affil'])['Donation'].sum()
```

You also mention wanting to group together:

```
df['datetime_obj_min'] = df['datetime_ob'].dt.minute
df.sort_values(['datetime_obj_min', 'Affil'], inplace=True)
```

Hopefully that helps.